# Spring Property place holder / multiple applications within the same tomcat/jvm

Tags: spring, properties

Is there a way to use Spring 3 property place holder to load application specific properties without conflicting with other applications within the same tomcat/jvm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your application specific properties are residing inside your jar and tomcat will only make them available to your application. 
Just put them under webapps/${app_war}/WEB-INF/classes/app.properties and your spring config will pick them up from classpath.

System properties via -D startup parameters are shared, but not application specific.